# "java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context is empty" Exception while making downstream request using WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am trying to upgrade to spring boot 2.6.6 from 2.2.0.RELEASE. Upon migrating I found that I was getting the below mentioned exception while making downstream calls using webclient. So I started checking with lower versions of spring boot and I found that my implementation is working fine in Spring Boot 2.6.3. But upgrading to spring boot version 2.6.4 I am getting this error.

JDK version: openjdk 17.0.2

**Error**:

> class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException | Cause : java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context is empty | Exception message : Context is empty; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context is empty | StackTrace : org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)

What changed in spring boot 2.6.4 that I am getting this error? And what changes can i make to my code to fix that.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    webClient = WebClient.create();
    
}

public Mono<?> postRequest(final String url, final Object request,
                           final MultiValueMap headers, final MediaType contentType, final MediaType acceptType) {
    Mono<?> response;
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        long webClientStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        response = webClient.post().uri(uri)
            .contentType(contentType)
            .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                if (Objects.nonNull(headers)) {
                    httpHeaders.addAll(headers);
                }
            })
            .bodyValue(request)
            .accept(acceptType)
            .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                log.info("clientResponse.statusCode(): {}, path: {}, webClient latency: {}",
                    clientResponse.statusCode(), uri.getPath(), System.currentTimeMillis() - webClientStartTime);
                if (!clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    return Mono.error(new BaseException("Not success response received from downstream. HttpCode: " +  clientResponse.statusCode()));
                }
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
            })
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("clientResponse error: {}, path: {}, webclient latency: {}",
                throwable, uri.getPath(), System.currentTimeMillis() - webClientStartTime));
        return response;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Some exception while processing post request. Error: {}",  ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please try with version 2.6.8, it might be related to this issue https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/pull/2110

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @VioletaGeorgieva, upgrading to Spring boot 2.6.8 has fixed the issue.